# What is my liability for third-party content I host?

Tags: united-states, internet, canada, liability, ownership

I live in Canada, but my servers are hosted by a third party in the United States. I run a forum-type website, so most content is provided by users.

Do I have any liability for illegal content that users may post, including:

1. Threats
2. Libel
3. Copyrighted materials
4. Child pornography

How do large companies like Facebook avoid liability or other legal problems for such illegal content?

Comment: Large companies do not *avoid* liability; they manage it by employing teams of lawyers and programmers to do so.

Comment: Related question: [Website liability for user contributed content that may be unlawful?](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/6970/10)